# React Redux - Calling a function from within a simple action cause "not a function" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have an action located in the file reduxer.js (thats reached) called "logoutUser()":

```
export const logoutUser = () =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    clearJwt()
      ({ type: LOGOUT_USER })
  }
```

I have the function "clearJwt()" which is in the file jwt.js:

```
export const clearJwt = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem(TOKEN_KEY)
}
```

I get this error when it reaches "clearJwt()":

```
reducer.js:77 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jwt.clearJwt)(...) is not a function
at reducer.js:77
at index.js:11
at Object.logoutUser (LogoutContainer.jsx:28)
at LogoutContainer.componentDidMount (LogoutContainer.jsx:14)
at LogoutContainer.proxiedComponentDidMount (createPrototypeProxy.js:61)
```

jwt.js is imported as per this line in the reducer.js file:

```
import { saveJwt, getJwt, clearJwt } from '../auth/jwt'
```

I have called this function in other places in particular a catch that appears in another function just above this function

```
    .catch(error => {
    clearJwt()
    dispatch({ type: ERROR_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: error.message })
  })
```

..and this works!

However, it throws the above error in my logoutUser() function.

It should just go to that function but it errors instead.. could someone point me in the right direction..

Comment: Are you missing a `{` after `export const logoutUser = () =>` Also try to call `dispatch({ type: LOGOUT_USER })`

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the return value of `clearJwt()` here:

```
clearJwt()
  ({ type: LOGOUT_USER })
```

So `clearJwt()` is called, but it returns `undefined` (since it's a block arrow function with no `return` statement). Then *that* value will be called (that's the second line), but this fails because, as the error message states, "undefined is not a function".

Comment: How would I structure this correctly so it just runs that function and not returns undefined.. wondering if you could edit your question to reflect it ...and no I didnt screw up the second line indent.. :( I actually didnt have dispatch in the front.. duh.

Comment: @si2030 It's unclear to me exactly what your intention is, in particular with `({ type: LOGOUT_USER })`. Where does that come from, and what is it supposed to do? And just to clarify: it's not that `clearJwt` isn't being called, it's just that it will also try to call whatever is returned by that function (undefined)—that's what the second line does.

Comment: I fixed this by adding a return true in the function clearJWT(). Now it clears the JWT and resets the Authorized state value to false thereby re-rendering the navbar to show "login" and those options not requiring authorized.